# How to read PDFs created with an unknown random owner password?

Tags: java, pdf, passwords, itext, aspose

Requirement is to process a batch of PDF's one at a time and on success encrypt each of them with an user password.

However, these PDF's were encrypted previously with randomly generated dynamic owner password *(not know to any one)* to prevent any edits.

I use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) for encryption as shown below:

```
byte[] userPass = "user".getBytes();
byte[] ownerPass = "owner".getBytes();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Misc.pdf");

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
            new FileOutputStream("Processed_Encrypted.pdf"));
stamper.setEncryption(userPass, ownerPass,
PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128
        | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

But this code throws an `com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.BadPasswordException: PdfReader not opened with owner password`

Can some one guide on how to resolve this error / bypass owner password?

Here I would like to make clear that we legally own these PDFs, so no crime / hacking is committed.

**P.S.**: Solution isn't limited to iText, can use any other Java library (*Free or licensed*) too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`PdfReader` has an undocumented `static boolean` variable named `unethicalreading`. For obvious reasons, this variable is set to `false` by default. You could set this variable to true like this:

```
PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
```

From now on, PdfReader will ignore the presence of an owner password. It will only throw an exception if a user password is in place.

Use this at your own risk.

Comment: Check out this alternative workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/36176562/3227457 if you're stuck with iText 2.1.7 for licensing reasons