# Using iTextSharp.text how to allow all security settings except 'Document Assembly & Page Extraction'?

Tags: c#, itext

[image: PDF Security Requirement]

Hi I am using iTextSharp.text in c# and I have requirement to set the following security settings to the PDF that is generated. 
I have tried following but it sets password and still allows page extraction.

```
PDFEncryptor pdfe = new PDFEncryptor(null, ~(PdfWriter.AllowAssembly));
pdfImg= pdfe.Encrypt(pdfImg);
```

How to solve this?

Comment: are you trying to prevent editing of the PDF

Comment: Instead of picking the properties that you want to exclude and inverting the bit components, try just setting the explicit properties that you want to allow. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179177/disallow-editing-but-allow-page-extraction-in-java-itext-pdf) has a table of them and you can find their equivalent constants in the `PdfWriter` class.

Comment: Additionally to what @ChrisHaas wrote, you also may want to read [Allow page extraction in a password security pdf with itextsharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783530/allow-page-extraction-in-a-password-security-pdf-with-itextsharp) where you'll find how the *bits* described in the PDF specification map to iText constants.

Comment: How can I set Security Method to "No security" in addition to the document restrictions? I am passing null to PDFEncyptor constructor but still is sets password.

Comment: I figured out that I should not encrypt at all. If I open the PDF with Adobe xl PRO everything listed is allowed but if I open with Acrobat reader 11.0.12 I see what I was looking for.