# BadPasswordException: Bad user password

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am creating an encrypted PDF using this code:

```
Document document = new Document(
    new Rectangle(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getHeight()));
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
    new FileOutputStream(RESULT1));
writer.setBoxSize("art", new Rectangle(36, 54, 555, 791));
writer.setEncryption("Vibhu".getBytes(), "Vibhu@123456789".getBytes(),
    PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
document.open();
// Creating Tables and Cells
document.close();
```

I omitted to code that creates cells and tables and the code that creates a form in which values such as firstname, lastname can be entered.

Then I manipulate the form like this.

```
private void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest, EclaimsVO eclaimsVO,
    String language) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File file = new File(src);
    if (isObjectPresent(file)) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfStamper stamper;
        stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest),
                '\0', false);
        form = stamper.getAcroFields();
        addToForm("field_2", eclaimsVO.getName());
        addToForm("field_3", eclaimsVO.getSurName());
        stamper.close();
    }
}
```

I have been trying to add a password to a PDF file by `setEncryption()` when I create the file, but it throws this exception when I read the file:

```
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.BadPasswordException: Bad user password
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:681)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:181)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:219)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:207)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:197)
```

But, if I change the unethicalreading to true and set the OWNER-PASSWORD as an empty string the exception doesn't come up.

```
writer.setEncryption("".getBytes(), "Vibhu@123456789".getBytes(),
            PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
```

And now when I try opening the PDF it gets opened without a password prompt.
But the document has a "Sample.pdf(SECURED)" title when I open the PDF.

Comment: There's something strange about your question. Looking at your code, it's as if you want to *set* passwords while *creating* a document. As far as I know the error you mention only occurs when you try to *read* an *existing* document without a password. Can you clarify? Are you creating or manipulating an existing document. You should provide more code.

Comment: Yes, I want to set a password while creating a document. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: In that case, I don't understand (1.) why you get the exception since you are not using `PdfReader` and (2.) why you are setting `unethicalreading` to `true` because you don't need to *decrypt* anything, you only want to *encrypt* a PDF. So once again I am asking you: show more code. No more code = no more answers or comments (and the risk that I vote to close the question as unclear).

Comment: I read a post here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955620/how-to-read-pdfs-created-with-an-unknown-random-owner-password) and hence used unethicalreading to true. I was trying. I have edited the code.

Comment: I have updated your question. When I asked: are you creating or manipulating the code, you didn't answer correctly. You should be more accurate in the future!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First allow me to focus on some details:

```
Document document = new Document(
    new Rectangle(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getHeight()));
```

The constance `A4` is a `Rectangle` object with a specific width and height. You can use it like this:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
```

Why are you creating yet another rectangle? `new Rectangle(PageSize.A4.getWidth(), PageSize.A4.getHeight())` is the equivalent of `PageSize.A4`, so why aren't you just using `PageSize.A4`?

Why are you defining an art box?

writer.setBoxSize("art", new Rectangle(36, 54, 555, 791));

There is usually very little reason to create an Art box. Why not remove this line?

**Now for the essence of your question:**

*First counter-question:*

It seems that you are creating a form that you later want to fill out. If this form is meant for private use, why are you encrypting the form? Why not encrypt it during the process of filling it out? Wouldn't that simplify things?

*Short description of what you're doing:*

Suppose that you really want to encrypt the template. In that case, you know the owner password:

```
writer.setEncryption("Vibhu".getBytes(), "Vibhu@123456789".getBytes(),
    PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
```

You also tried:

```
writer.setEncryption("".getBytes(), "Vibhu@123456789".getBytes(),
    PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
```

You claim that you *set the OWNER-PASSWORD as an empty string*. That is **not true!** You are using an empty `String` for the *user password*. The *user* password is the password that an end user (a human being who want to read the document) needs to enter when he wants to open the document. The *owner* password is the password *unknown to the user* that is introduced by the person creating the document. This person will use that password when he wants to change something in the document, for instance: when he wants to fill out a form.

*Second counter-question:*

Why are you using this line:

```
PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
```

This line is what people use when they don't know the owner password. However, **you do know the owner password:** it's `"Vibhu@123456789"`.

*The simple solution to avoid a BadPasswordException:*

Since you *know* the owner password, you should use it when reading the document. This is explained in my answer to the question [How can I decrypt a PDF document with the owner password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867868/how-can-i-decrypt-a-pdf-document-with-the-owner-password)

You should update the line where you create the `reader` object like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src, "Vibhu@123456789".getBytes());
```

Now you will no longer get a `BadPasswordException` and you can safely fill out your form.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thanks for your patience as well.

Comment: Ho @DvD: if the answer solved your problem, please accept the answer.