# iText - read PDFs created with an unknown random owner password

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-reader

I'm getting the following exception when excecuting this code:

```
public byte[] watermarking(byte[] orig) throws IOException {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(orig);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = null;

        try {
            pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, baos); //exc here
            ...
            }
            ...
        } catch (DocumentException var8) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Exception:

```
11:43:11,094 ERROR [de.mlp.xbg.pa.rest.SessionRR] (http-/127.0.0.1:8081-6) PdfReader not opened with owner password: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PdfReader not opened with owner password
```

I checked other threads regarding this topic and it seems that the easiest solution is to add `PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;`

However, I'm forced to use iText 2.1.7 or older *(`com.lowagie` iText)* and not iText 5.0.0 or newer *(`com.itextpdf` iText)*. `PdfReader.unethicalreading` does not exist in the old version of the library.

Comment: Why are you forced to use an ancient and unmaintained version of iText that doesn't contain the feature you need?

Comment: If you look at the source code (https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/develop/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.java) then you will see that `unethicalreading` was added in iText 5.0.2 _(`com.itextpdf` iText)_. More precisely, in this commit: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/commit/c27c608dee1495b91dc290653b1f387d7c09adde on Mar 31, 2010. Which means you are using a version of iText that is at least 6 years old.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](http://www.pdfsam.org/pdf-split-and-merge/if-you-have-the-error-message-pdfreader-not-opened-with-owner-password/323/) there seems to be a workaround to make iText to ignore password **with a disclaimer**:

> **I leave legal issues up to you** by executing the code below.

```
public static PdfReader unlockPdf(PdfReader reader) {
    if (reader == null) {
        return reader;
    }
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field f = reader.getClass().getDeclaredField("encrypted");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(reader, false);
    } catch (Exception e) { /* ignore */ }
    return reader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For OpenPDF there's a property on PdfReader that does the magic:

```
/**
   * Sets whether the document (if encrypted) may be modified even if the owner password was not
   * supplied. If this is set to <CODE>false</CODE> an exception will be thrown when attempting to
   * access the Document if the owner password was not supplied (for encrypted documents.)
   *
   * @param modificationAllowedWithoutOwnerPassword
   *         the modificationAllowedWithoutOwnerPassword state.
   */
  public void setModificationAllowedWithoutOwnerPassword(
    boolean modificationAllowedWithoutOwnerPassword) {
    this.modificationAllowedWithoutOwnerPassword = modificationAllowedWithoutOwnerPassword;
  }
```

Code Example:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(byteArray);
reader.setModificationAllowedWithoutOwnerPassword(true);        

reader.addViewerPreference(PdfName.HIDE, PdfBoolean.PDFFALSE);
reader.addViewerPreference(PdfName.HIDEWINDOWUI,PdfBoolean.PDFFALSE);
        
// encrypt e sai para byte array
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfEncryptor.encrypt(reader, os, null, null, permissions, true);
reader.close();
```

Source: https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF/pull/84